# Can you use Foundation Icons within Foundation pre/postfix labels and actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I am attempting to use a calendar icon from Foundation Icon set next to a rails form input, and figured a quick way to align the two while making it look good was to use Foundation's postfix labels.  Here is my code followed by a screenshot, which shows that they are compatible, but the main priority of getting them to be aligned with each other fails to happen:

```
<div class="row collapse">
  <div class="fourteen mobile-three columns">
    <label for="fundraiser-expire-at">End Date</label>
    <%= form.text_field 'expire_at',
                        class: 'datepicker' %>
  </div>
  <div class="two mobile-one columns">
    <span class="postfix">
      <i class="general enclosed foundicon-calendar show_datepicker"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: postfix label isn't aligned with input!]

Does anyone know a way I can get what I'm looking for hear?  Will it require css?  I'm sure that css is A solution, I'm just wondering if I can use Foundation built in styling to get this working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contemplated deleting this question because it ended up being a really easy fix, but I figured that SOMEONE, SOMEWHERE, MIGHT benefit from this question persisting.  The problem lies with the label being in the same section of fourteen columns as the input.  The postfix does its best to align with the combo of the label and input.  If you put the label outside the fourteen columns so that the input is the only member of that section, the postfix aligns itself with the input.

Comment: +1 Yes, I needed it and it helped me! Thanks! Ps.: I am going to add an extra answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Jake Smiths's answer I will show where to change to make it the postfix get nicely aligned with the field. The example bellow uses Foundation 5.1.1 and Ruby on Rails 3.2.

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 columns">
      <div class="row collapse">
        <div class="small-9 columns">
          <%= f.label :altitude %> <!-- This line here must be moved outside this div -->
          <%= f.text_field :altitude %>
        </div>
        <div class="small-3 columns">
          <span class="postfix radius">meters</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This results in an not aligned field and label.

If we change it to:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 columns">
      <div class="row collapse">
        <%= f.label :altitude %> <!-- Now it is happy and aligned :-) -->
        <div class="small-9 columns">
          <%= f.text_field :altitude %>
        </div>
        <div class="small-3 columns">
          <span class="postfix radius">meters</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```